# Computer Vision API - v1.0 Get Handwritten Text Operation Result doesn't recognize blue pen

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Is there a way that handwritten text written with a **blue** pen like in below screenshot gets recognized, too? The **black** written text is recognized.

API: [Computer Vision API - v1.0 Get Handwritten Text Operation Result](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/587f2cf1154055056008f201)

[image: Result]

Comment: You could do a preprocessing step and convert your input image to gray scale or black and white.

Comment: @denvercoder Is that possible via azure api ? Or could you provide a solution? Thanks.

Comment: @denvercoder I tried currently with image in gray scale and black and white but get same result.

Answer (score -1):

[I work on this OCR API at Microsoft]

I think there are 2 challenges here:

- Your image has an overall blue hue, making blue ink harder to distinguish compared to black.
- Stylized writing for the time (I think?)

Latter is a tough one, as I don't believe we have such examples in our training data in appreciable volume.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/home here is mentioned that cursive text may not be recognized. In addition Subscript and Superscript text like my timestamp. I tried same image as black and white with same negativ result